# Populating description properties for a product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]

I'd like to display description for my product in properties area, but can't find where can I put this information. For features this information is gathered from "description" element of a feature, but what about the product?

Comment: Probably the 'description' element of the 'product' declaration in the 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.products' extension point declaring the product.

Comment: @greg-449 Tried it, it does not reflect in description area unfortunately.